# How to execute one command conditionally based on the result of another?

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

I put together two commands in ReactiveUI: CheckNetwork and CheckVersion. Any time CheckNetwork executes (and it is executing at the correct times) I'd like to execute CheckVersion - but only if CheckNetwork returned "true".

```
ReactiveCommand<Unit, bool> CheckNetwork { get; }
ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> CheckVersion { get; }

CheckVersion = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(CheckVersionImpl);
CheckNetwork = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(CheckNetworkImpl);
```

I've tried a bunch of things so won't go through them all, just can't seem to get anything working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
CheckNetwork
.Where(result => result)
.Select(_=> Unit.Default)
.InvokeCommand(CheckVersion);
```

Comment: Right on, Shane, thank you! The Select of the empty Unit is the "ah!" moment for me... :-)